# Postgres backup database

Tags: django, database, postgresql, database-backups

I'm working on a django project and i'm using postgres for database. I want to backup the database and i tried to use dbbackup library. While in development env works fine in production i got an error of no password.
The command i'm running is the same in both environments and also the configuration, the only difference is the database credentials

```
Backing Up Database: database
CommandConnectorError: Error running:  pg_dump  --host=localhost --username=databaseuser --no-password --clean database 
pg_dump: error: connection to database "database" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "databaseuser"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "databaseuser"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well... figure out what the correct credentials are and use them? It's really quite hard to say much else here.

Comment: Look in the database log file for the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

downgraded from 3.2.0 to 3.0

pip uninstall django-dbbackup

pip install django-dbbackup==3.0